# How can we create procedure in BigSQL?

Tags: bigsql

I am trying to create procedure in BigSQL. where i got some syntax error since i used db2 systax.Could you please tell me. what is the systax for procedure creation in BigSQL.

Comment: Please provide information about the syntax you executed and what kind of error it returned. It will be easier for others to understand your problem then.

Comment: What version of BigSQL are you using? I am going to post the link to the syntax for BigSQL as part of IBM BigInsights 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the BigSQL syntax can be found here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.db2biga.doc/doc/biga_intro.html?lang=en

However, as noted, you probably are dealing with a specific syntax issue and you should post the code for the procedure you created.